# How much space is my google account ACTUALLY taking up?

Tags: google-drive

I use Gmail and Google Drive for work (at a public school in the US).  When I enter Drive and open settings, my storage reports this:

[image]

This looks to be about right to me, as I have several large audio/video files that take up a significant amount of space.

But when I look at the little readout at the bottom my of Gmail inbox, it shows this:

[image]

I can't imagine how I would ever take up 22,000 GB of space!  So, what's going on here?

Comment: Oooooh I never thought about that!  I think you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Ramhound it's now migrated (seems that you are actually a member of the community here...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is likely a side effect of your using a Google Account associated with a school, as the individual Google Account indicates the usage out of the total storage you have available. Which likely means 22TB is the amount the entire master account for the school is using. I suggest contacting the school's administrator for more information.

From [Ramhound's comment on the original question prior to migration](https://superuser.com/questions/1789942/how-much-space-is-my-google-account-actually-taking-up?noredirect=1#comment2800372_1789942)